# When accessing a DB2 database via COBOL, how can one set the Isolation Level, Fetch Size, Scroll Type and Concurrency? (among other performance tips)

Tags: database, performance, db2, cobol

I'm coming from a Java perspective, and when I last optimized database access for Java, I used methods such as:

setTransactionIsolation()
setFetchSize()

and set settings like:

ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE
ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY

Would anyone know how to apply these kinds of performance enhancements in COBOL? And what other performance enhancements in general can one apply to DB2 access via COBOL to speed-up processes?

Comment: Talk to the DBA team as well. There may be things which they can improve but which COBOL (SQL actually) has no direct control over. You did do that for your Java didn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For COBOL you need to set the isolation level on the SQL statement using a "WITH" clause in your SQL;

```
SELECT * FROM MY.TESTTABLE
WITH UR;
```

Would set the isolation level to "Uncommitted Read" which will never lock, but will give you uncommitted updates.

Other options are:

"RR" Repeatable Read -- lock read rows so that they can be read again.

"RS" Read Stability -- some rows locked

"CS" Cursor Stability -- current/next row in cursor is locked

You can also set the default Isolation Level on the plan or package BIND with the "ISOLATION" clause.

These levels map to their ANSI equivalents [ANSI Equivalents](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2e/v9r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2e.doc/db2e_iso_levels.html)

Comment: Wow, great! I hope these improve performance as I'm accessing huge database objects.